# How can I make my anchor tags move to the right side of navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code using bootstrap navbar. But I want to make the anchor tags move the right side when one is seeing them full screen on laptop. How do I do that? If you can please show the CSS as well. Thank you!

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">J & M Residential Cleaning Services</a>
                  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                  </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                          <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Book Online</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To align the text to the right in the dropdown, set **[`text-align: right`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)** on `.navbar-collapse`:

```css
.collapse.navbar-collapse {
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">J & M Residential Cleaning Services</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Book Online</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

If instead you'd like to align the row of links in the expanded view, things get a little more complicated. Bootstrap 4 has switched to a **[flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)** layout, and as such, you'll need to target `.collapse.navbar-collapse`, setting **[`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items)** to `flex-end` and change the **[`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)** to `column-reverse`:

```
.collapse.navbar-collapse {
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

This can be seen in the following (click `Run code snippet` then `Full page`):

```css
.navbar- {
  text-align: right;
}

.collapse.navbar-collapse {
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">J & M Residential Cleaning Services</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Book Online</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Ok thanks,but I'm needing to make them move to the right side of the navbar when you are seeing it for example in the laptop.

Comment: Oh, I misinterpreted. My apologies. I've updated my answer to cover that as well :)